# Gdal ogrinfo CSV unable to open datasource

Tags: gdal, ogr, csv, ogr2ogr

When I try to import a csv file into a PostgreSQL table with the Gdal ogr2ogr tool I get the "Unable to open datasource" Failure.
So I tried to open it with the tool ogrinfo and I get the same Failure.

I use it in a Ubuntu 10.10, with the package gdal-bin version 1.6.3-4build1.

This is the command:

```
> ogrinfo test.csv
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `test.csv' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  ...
  -> CSV
  ...
```

This is the content of the "test.csv" file:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
1;a;row1;11
2;b;row2;22
3;c;row3;33
4;d;row4;44
5;e;row5;55
6;f;row6;66
```

Any help?

Could it be the version of gdal bin? kind of old OS I know.

Comment: Is the separator between column 3 and 4 actually a comma instead of a semicolon like the rest, or is that a typo?

Comment: It would be a typo sorry. Ok, let me edit the question to simplify the csv test file. I know anyway the failure persists.

Comment: Possibly the user has no right to read the CSV?

Comment: Could it be the version of gdal bin? kind of old OS I know..

Comment: Might be, GDAL 1.6 is 7 years old http://www.osgeo.org/node/801. My GDAL 2.1-dev can read your file just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think the problem is with the Gdal-Bin version. I tried in the same environment another csv file but with comma separator, not semicolon, and it worked.

Then I tried the "test.csv" with semicolon separator in my home pc, with the version of gdal-bin 1.7.3-6ubuntu3, and it was imported perfectly.

So my conclusion is that the gdal-bin version 1.6.3-4build1 has some problems importing CSV files with semicolon separator.

Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: Why dont you install the latest gdal version?

Comment: Yes, I will, but first I will have to update the Server OS, because I am developing a functionality in a Web Server, and before this I have to arrange some other dependencies. Don't worry, thank you, but with this conclusion I take this question as Solved:)